# Android programming repeat runnable images

Tags: java, android

Hi i have these set of codes and what i want is that when the process is finished it will repeat again on the first image. how can i do it?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fingerspellingout);
    gotWord = getIntent().getExtras();
    get = gotWord.getString("key");
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_alpha);
    //ttsbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

    getArray= get.toCharArray();

    charIndex = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new ImageTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 2000);

}
public class ImageTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    ImageTimerTask imageTimerTask = this;

    @Override
    public void run() {
            System.out.println("charIndex: " + charIndex);
            System.out.println("this: " + getArray[charIndex]);
            System.out.println("get length: " + get.length());


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    System.out.println("run UI thread!");
                    InputStream is;
                    try {

                        if(getArray[charIndex]==' ')
                        {
                            charIndex++;
                        }

                        is = getResources().getAssets().open(getArray[charIndex] + ".png");
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        charIndex++;

                        if(charIndex == get.length()){
                            System.out.println("cancel!");
                            imageTimerTask.cancel();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
    }
}
```

this is my code...

Comment: i don't know where you guys are getting that crappy samples from (TimerTask + runOnUiThread + Runnables etc)... all you need to do what you want is a simple Handler

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` instead of `schedule`

And `charIndex` should be reset to 0

```
if(charIndex == get.length()){
   charIndex=0;
}
```

Or you can use `AnimationDrawable` to show an animation repeatly

Comment: when would you want to stop it??

Comment: when it repeat 2-3 times like that or something.

Comment: you may add a integer counter to count number of repeat. while the counter reach your target number, call timerTask.cancel()